# log level in diagnostics package

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
As we can see that below API can be used for setting the default log level for console. can anybody suggest how to set the leg level for diagnostics.Here same i am expecting i.e. (ros::diagnostics_updater::levels::Debug)

ros::console::set_logger_level(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, ros::console::levels::Debug)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257495/log-level-in-diagnostics-package./) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Diagnostics does not have a threshold to control if messages are sent of not. It is up the receiving nodes to decide if they want to discard e.g. info level diagnostics messages.

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2018-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1